# Find the cell in n*m matrix(containing 0s and 1s) with maximum neighbours(in all 8 directions) 1

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Recently I was asked this question in an interview:

> Given a n*m matrix with 0 and 1 only, find the cell which satisfies
>   the following condition:
>
> The cell has one and max of its neighbors in all possible 8 directions
>   have same number as it has i.e. 1.

All I could think of is brute force which would be O(n*m).Any better ideas?

Thanks.

Eg:

```
0 1 1

0 1 0

1 1 1
```

Here, the required cell is `(1,1)`.

Comment: Well you atleast have to go to every possible cell to find the answer, so it is the best that can be achieved.

Comment: But the interviewer kept on telling me that there is a better solution

Comment: With the information given I am afraid that's the best that is possible.

Comment: Maybe they wanted you to justify why there cannot be better solution? If by max you mean majority, some cells may be skipped but that would be based on the density of 1's in the table. Was it the worst case complexity?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the " max you mean majority, some cells may be skipped " part . And how do we do that.

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/ow2XVDv.png) I don't need to know the value of C1 because i) it cannot satisfy the conditions ii) its value does not affect other cells status. I cannot eliminate D2 because whether D3 satisfies the conditions or not depends on that. If I look at D4 and see that it is zero, now I can eliminate D2 too.